# Aesthetics : fill - Warning ocours when ploting gg Boxplot

Tags: ggplot2, colors, boxplot

Ive written a R-chunk which should provide me a coloured ggplot boxplot. All needed templates are loaded, so is the Data.

The Data for „Healthy“ & „BodyTemperature“ is based inside the Data „Hospital“.
For Healthy there can be only 0 oder 1.

It should plott two Boxplots next to each other on the x-axis, one showing Healthy (0) the other one Unhealthy (1) compared to the BodyTemperature of the patients on y-axis.
The Boxplot should be coloured with the Template „Brewer“.

Everytime i try to run this chunk, a warning occours. Whats the solution?

**colour:**

```
colour <- brewer.pal(n = 2, name = "Set1")
colour
```

Warnung: minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
[1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A"

**R-Chunk**

```
colour = brewer.pal(n = 2, name = "Set1")

ggplot(Hospital, aes(x = Healthy, y = BodyTemperature)) +
geom_boxplot(fill=c(colour)) +
  ylab("Temperature") + 
  xlab("Healthy") +
  ggtitle("Health compared to Temperature")
```

**Warning ocours:**

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): fill
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2 (local) by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_geom_2(d))
  6. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
  7. l$compute_geom_2(d)
  8. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)
  9. self$geom$use_defaults(data, self$aes_params, modifiers)
 10. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)
 11. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(params[aes_params], nrow(data))
 Error in check_aesthetics(params[aes_params], nrow(data)) :
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to color your boxplots by the value of `Healthy` you could do so by mapping `Healthy` on the `fill` aesthetic. Also to use one of the Brewer palettes `ggplot2` already offers some convenience functions which in case of the `fill` aes is called `scale_fill_brewer`. Not sure whether you want a legend but IMHO it does not make sense so I removed it via `guides`. Finally as you provided no data it's not clear whether your `Healthy` column is a numeric or a categorical variable. For this reason I wrapped in `factor` to make it categorical.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)

Hospital <- data.frame(
  Healthy = rep(c(0, 1), 50),
  BodyTemperature = runif(100)
)

ggplot(Hospital, aes(x = factor(Healthy), y = BodyTemperature)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(Healthy))) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  xlab("Healthy") +
  ggtitle("Health compared to Temperature") +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Stefan, ive seen your from Germany so it would be easy to change:

Comment: Herzlichen Dank für die schnelle Antwort!!

Comment: Ich habe für "Healthy" eine Spalte in der Datentabelle, bestehend aus 0 und 1. 

Wofür stehen diese Ausrücke?

set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)

Hospital <- data.frame(
  Healthy = rep(c(0, 1), 50),
  BodyTemperature = runif(100)
)

Es hat aufjeden Fall schon funktioniert. Ich habe das identische Problem noch bei einem gg Histogram - ich werde es gleich ausprobieren!

Comment: Gerne.  Der Ausdruck erstellt einen Beispieldatensatz mit 50 0en und 1en für die Variable `Healthy` und 100 Zufallswerten aus einer Gleichverteilung für die Variable `BodyTemperature`. `set.seed(123)` stellt sicher, dass du oder jede:r andere die gleichen "Zufallswerte" erhält. 123 ist dabei beliebig. Auch ein genereller Hinweis für die Zukunft: Stets einen Beispieldatensatz oder einen Teil deines Datensatzes zur Verfügung stellen. Siehe hierzu [How to make great  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Und auch wenn wir beide auf Deutsch kommunizieren können: Besser auf Englisch, damit auch andere die Hinweise und Kommentare lesen und verstehen können. (:

Comment: Okay vielen Dank - ich arbeite am Histogramm — ich antworte nachher auf diese Nachricht in english

Comment: If you feel more comfortable in German, may I propose the German R forum at forum.r-statistik.de ?